# Where do I tell AWS SAM which file to chose depending on the stage/environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

In the app.js, I want to require a different "config" file depending on the stage/account.
for example:
dev account:  `const config = require("config-dev.json")`
prod account: `const config = require("config-prod.json")`

At first I tried passing it using `build --container-env-var-file` but after getting `undefined` when using `process.env.myVar`, I think that env file is used at the build stage and has nothing to do with my function, but I could use it in the template creation stage..

So I'm looking now at deploy and there are a few different things that seem relevant, but it's quite confusing to chose which one is relevant for my use case.

There is the config file, in which case, I have no idea how to configure it since I'm in a pipeline context, so where would I instruct my process to use the correct json?

There is also parameters, and mapping.
My json is not just a few vars. its a bit of a complex object. nothing crazy not simple enough to pass the vars 1 by 1.

So I thought a single one containing the filename that I want to use could do the job

But I have no idea how to tell which stage of deployment I currently am in, or how to pass that value to access it from the lambda function.

Comment: Do you maybe use aws amplify?

Comment: I looked into it but it's quite an overkill for my little initiative imo @bill.gates

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this issue while exectuing aws lambda function locally.By this command my issue was solved.
try to configure your file using the `sam build` command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would also like a bit more info about how you used sam build. Which flag or options did you use and how?